# Displaying large PDF document iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pdf, core-graphics

After many hours of googling I thought I would see if anyone knew the answer.

I have a large PDF file (30mb) which I was using the UIWebView to display but it is painfully slow when trying to scroll through pages and when you rotate the iPhone/iPad it doesn't draw properly on the screen till you have scrolled through a few pages.

So I have been looking into using the CGPDFDocumentRef to display the PDF.  Before I go any further is there an easier way to do this, or any examples/open source solutions to do this before I spend a long time trying to replicate the UIWebView or something similar to display a large PDF.

I assume someone else has had this problem?

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been building one of these for a while now. I'll tell you, both approaches have difficulties. The CGPDFDocumentRef path is the one that I've taken, and it's worked out pretty well.

A good place to start is here, with Apple's example, [ZoomingPDFViewer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html). You'll get a good idea of how that CGPDF* stuff works. If you're looking to put something together in a hurry, you might want to start with this guy's [example](https://github.com/vfr/Reader). In fact, the [author's website](http://www.vfr.org/) has a huge list of resources to use when you run into problems.

Comment: That's great, thanks very much, I'll have a look over the code and see what's going on.  After running it I think my step will be to get it to display pages side by side when it landscape..... as soon as I figure out how to do that!